# GWT ScrollPanel get max size of children without scrolling

Tags: gwt, scroll

I was wondering is there any possibility to get the inner size of a

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel
```

object in GWT? I would like to create a children of the ScrollPanel that fits exactly into the  empty space, without activating the scroll bars. 
The ScrollPanel is initialized as follows:

[begin update after answer of @Abhijith Nagaraja]

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Window.setMargin("0px");

    TabLayoutPanel tabs = new TabLayoutPanel(30, Unit.PX);

    //attach the tab panel to the body element
    RootPanel.get(null).add(tabs);

    //set the TabLayoutPanel to full size of the window.
    String width = (Window.getClientWidth()) + "px";
    String height = (Window.getClientHeight()) + "px";
    tabs.setSize(width, height);

    //create the scroll panel and activate the scroll bars
    ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel(new Button("a second button"));
    scrollPanel.getElement().getStyle().setOverflowX(Overflow.SCROLL); 
    scrollPanel.getElement().getStyle().setOverflowY(Overflow.SCROLL);

    //attach the scroll panel to the DOM
    tabs.add(scrollPanel, "tab1");

    System.out.println(scrollPanel.getOffsetWidth());       // --> 0
    System.out.println(scrollPanel.getOffsetHeight());      // --> 0

}
```

[end update]

Reason: I want to initialize a dynamic visualization (which requires scrollbars at a later point in time) in such a way that, it looks nice and avoiding to add the ScrollPanel later.

Comment: First is scroll panel is from Simple panel, so only one child can be added, next to fill up the empty space need to increase the size of child to exactly scroll panel size. Hope this is what you are looking for, if not please explain it more..

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel();`

`...`

`int innerWidth = sp.`[getOffsetWidth()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetWidth%28%29)`- sp.getElement().`[getScrollWidth()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getScrollWidth%28%29)`;`

`...`

**NOTE:** *You can use the above code only if your scrollPanell is attached to the screen. In other words it should be rendered.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the solution, but I get always 0 for the getOffsetWidth() and getOffsetHeight(). The scroll panel is attached to the dom. Please find my update above.

Comment: Attached to the DOM doesn't help... It should be rendered on the screen... Once it should render then only you can adjust its width.

Comment: Is there a way to force the rendering process or to check whether the element has been rendered?

Answer (score 0):

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(scrollpanel.getElement(), "maxHeight", mMainHeight + "px");;
```